# Demonstrate this matrix derivative expression with the formulas of this table.

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, symmetric-matrices

I'm doing this problem:  Calculate $\frac{∂||Ax-b||^2}{∂x} = 2A^T (A-b) $.
Knowing that $\frac{∂||x||^2}{∂x} = 2x $ so far I have this:
$$\frac{∂||Ax-b||^2}{∂(Ax-b)} \frac{∂(Ax-b)}{∂x}  = 2(Ax-b)A$$

I don't know how to continue from there. To solve this I can use the following formulas:
$$1. \frac{∂x^t b}{∂x} = b$$
$$2. \frac{∂b^t x}{∂x} = b$$
$$3. \frac{∂Ax}{∂x} = A$$
$$4. \frac{∂x^tAx}{∂x} = 2Ax$$
$$5. \frac{∂x^tAx}{∂x} = (A+A^T)x$$

Comment: Does the expression $2(Ax-b)A$ make sense?

Comment: @Hyperplane maybe not, it's what I've guessed, sorry.

Comment: $A$ is symmetric matrix ?
Also if you take $A = I$ and $b = 0$ in your expressions, $\frac{∂||Ax-b||^2}{∂x} = 2A^T (A-b)$ becomes $\frac{∂||x||^2}{∂x} = 2$.

Comment: @qdr I don't know. In the previous exercice it's specified that A is symmetric while in this one it's not. But looking at the formulas it probably is.

Comment: @qdr Isn't $\frac{∂||x||^2}{∂x}=2x$?

Comment: Yes, so there's a typo in what you wrote here.

Comment: @qdr you're absolutely right. I just asked my teacher and he told me that instead of (A-b) it should say (Ax-b). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the product rule:
$$\begin{align}d_p||Ax-b||^2
&=d_p\langle Ax+b,Ax+b\rangle\\
&=2\langle Ap,Ax+b\rangle\\
&=\langle p,2A^T(Ax+b)\rangle,
\end{align}$$
hence the gradient of $||Ax+b||^2$ is $2A^T(Ax+b)$.